# Как исправить ошибку миграции unable to create an object of type 'FileContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Пытаюсь сделать первую миграцию для приложения при помощи команды Add-Migration Inittial. Вылетает ошибка `unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

Вот так выглядит мой файл Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at 
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
string connection = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); // Подключение локального подключения к Базе данныз mssql 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Вот так ApllicationContext.cs

```
namespace TaskManagerCourse.Api.Models.Data
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjectAdmin> ProjectAdmins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Desk> Desks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
            if(Users.Any(u => u.Status == UserStatus.Admin) == false) 
            {
                var admin = new User("test_name", "test_surnamme", "admin", "qwerty", UserStatus.Admin);
                Users.Add(admin);
                SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection" : "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TaskManagerDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

У меня подозрения на вот эту строчку `string connection = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");` Но возможно я не прав, подскажите, как решить данную проблему

Comment: попробуйте из конструктора контекста убрать весь код и перезапустить. Ну и убедитесь, что вы запускаете команду на нужном проекте. Плюс определитесь, у ваc FileContext или ApplicationContext

Comment: ApplicationContext, просто не помещалась длинна заголовка)

Comment: Если удляю код, он мне как раз кидает ошибка что надо настроить DbContext No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: Если оставляю конструктор пустым, то он выдает ту же самую ошибку, нахожусь в нужном проекте

Comment: По ссылке в ошибке описано, как утилита миграции создаёт контекст: ей нужен либо конструктор без параметров, либо хост, либо фабрика. Вы выбрали способ с созданием хоста. При использовании конструктора без параметров нужно было добавить метод `OnConfiguring`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос разделив на Program.Cs и на Startup.cs а как это сделать в рамках файла Program.cs так и не понял...

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //get connection string
            string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

           

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```